# Why qgis2web project is not displaying one WMS(OSM) in some machines?

Tags: wms, qgis2web

I have an HTML page generated by the plugin qgis2web. It has three WMS services in it. In my computer, all of them work fine. But there are some computers in which the WMS of the OpenStreetMap is not working (the others, for example Google, work).

Is there anything to do with a specific configuration of the browser in these machines? Or is there a setting of the HTML to which I should pay attention?

Comment: Open the webmap in a browser on one of the machines where it fails. Press F12. In the developer tools which should appear, look at the Console and Network tabs as you refresh the page. See if you can see any errors. Without that, it's going to be difficult to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was time out problem with the OSM wms.